# JSON parser error java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject] Array

Tags: php, android, json

Hi guys so my problem is ive developed an app for android that uses json parser to get data from my php webservice and display it into a listview, but when i run the app it shows this:

LogCat:

```
E/JSON Parser(1999): Error parsing data [Value Array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject] Array
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079): (
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [id] => 1
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [dt_ini_camp] => 2012-12-22
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [dt_fim_camp] => 2012-12-24
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [descricao] => Apoios comunit?rios
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [qtd] => 4762.000
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079): )
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079): Array
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079): (
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [id] => 2
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [dt_ini_camp] => 2012-10-08
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [dt_fim_camp] => 2012-10-10
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [descricao] => Outras Campanhas
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079):     [qtd] => 3560.000
04-02 13:46:46.982: E/JSON Parser(1079): )
```

My code:

Activity with list view and invokes json parser:

```
public class AllProductsActivity extends ListActivity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/webprojecto4/index_pesagem.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "cab_doc";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "descricao";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "dt_ini_camp";
private static final String TAG_DATA2 = "dt_fim_camp";
private static final String TAG_QTD = "qtd";

// products JSONArray
JSONArray products = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_products);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String id2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id)).getText()
                    .toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    EditProductActivity.class);
            // sending pid to next activity
            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);

            // starting new activity and expecting some response back
            startActivityForResult(in, 100);
        }
    });


}

// Response from Edit Product Activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // if result code 100
    if (resultCode == 100) {
        // if result code 100 is received
        // means user edited/deleted product
        // reload this screen again
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AllProductsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);


                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String data = c.getString(TAG_DATA);
                    String data2 = c.getString(TAG_DATA2);
                    String qtd = c.getString(TAG_QTD);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    map.put(TAG_DATA, data);
                    map.put(TAG_DATA2, data2);
                    map.put(TAG_QTD, qtd);
                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        NewProductActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        AllProductsActivity.this, productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_NAME, TAG_DATA, TAG_DATA2, TAG_QTD},
                        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.descricao, R.id.data, R.id.data2, R.id.qtd });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });

    }

}
}
```

Json Parser in this i only changed this line BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8); instead of utf-8 it was iso-8859-1 ive searched for this error and based on answers i found it said it would be better utf-8 but it didnt fixed the problem

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "utf-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data [" + e.getMessage()+"] "+json);
         }

    // return JSON String

    return jObj;

}
}
```

And my php service:

```
<?php

/*
* Following code will list all the products
*/

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/conectaDB.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("select cd.id, cd.dt_ini_camp, cd.dt_fim_camp, cd.descricao, + (select     sum(quantidade) from lin_doc where id_cab_doc = cd.id) as qtd from cab_doc cd where cd.id_tipo_doc =   1") or die(mysql_error());


 // check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// looping through all results
// products node

$response["cab_doc"] = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    // temp user array
    $product = array();
    $product["id"] = $row["id"];
    $product["dt_ini_camp"] = $row["dt_ini_camp"];
    $product["dt_fim_camp"] = $row["dt_fim_camp"];
    $product["descricao"] = $row["descricao"];
    $product["qtd"] = $row["qtd"];



    // push single product into final response array
  array_push($response["cab_doc"], $product);

  print_r($product);

}
// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no products found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No products found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Please guys i really need help i dont find the problem, the problem i find lol i dont find the answer to my problem xD

Answer (score 2):

You've a print_r() in your PHP code, which makes your output not JSON.

Comment: ive puted that print_r() because without it my php when i call it in browser it shows me a blanck page. And with it it shows me the results i want to display in my list view. I took him off and now the error is Error parsing data [End of input at character 0 of ]